# Node.js - Maximum time recommended in synchronous operations

Tags: javascript, node.js

Synchronous addon will block the event loop of Node.js. But perhaps, exists a "standard" limit admissible to block the event loop.

```
var results = addon.my_function(parameters); //consumes 2ms
```

My function consumes 2 ms. At this moment I am wondering if the work of change it to asynchronous way pays off the final performance.

Comment: _As little as possible_. The less it takes the more clients you'll be able to support. Although typically you can only perform I/O asynchronously.

Comment: look at it this way. By having a method that blocks for 2ms, you're limiting your app to handling no more than 500 requests per second (which isn't that bad for something that won't get near that much traffic.) You won't find a standard max recommended limit, instead you'll find suggestions recommending not blocking at all, or moving the blocking logic off to a different thread.

Comment: [link](http://blog.scottfrees.com/c-processing-from-node-js-part-4-asynchronous-addons) it is possible to make asynchronous addons @BenjaminGruenbaum . My question is to understand that exists a limit to  use asynchronous approach. If synchronous way was always bad, I think her existence itself is bad.

Comment: @zippo asynchronous CPU intensive actions are not friendly to node style. They effectively use threads and cause context switches.

Comment: Common rule of thumb is to avoid blocking, but you can make a judgement call depending on your project. Additional things to consider: Might this code be modified to be even slower later? Can it easily be modified to become async if so? How often does is the function called? Does that 2ms delay get propagated out to my users? If this runs on a slower machine in the future (or with other heavy processes simultaneously) does the 2ms become 10ms?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Node does nothing with threads or handling contexts. Its concurrency model is based on polling IO for completion(or partial completion for streaming). Both of which depend on an eventloop, not threads, subroutines, or anything involving contexts. An asynchronous method will take a callback, will simply add the IO even to the eventloop. Creating an "async" tasks for CPU intensive tasks will do nothing but pass your return value by calling a callback function rather than a return statement.

Comment: And thats not really async at all because asynchronous routines only happen for IO tasks which are implemented into nodejs's core modules, or with a native extension. This does not create a thread, and the are not multiple contexts in this type of concurrency.

Comment: This is what also makes nodejs's concurrency model extremely simple and eliminates almost all cases for race conditions to occur. Though also one of its main points for criticism because this type of concurrency does absolutely nothing to handle serial or CPU intensive tasks.

Comment: Another way to look at my second comment is someone would only need to be able to send 500 requests per second to your server to make it unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

As you likely know node.js has a concurrency model which only addresses concurrency of IO bound tasks. Any serial task that is not broken up will pause the event loop for that duration. It is possible to implement routines to break this task up, but it only suite specific paradigms. If you're doing a single operation which is going to take a lot of time then you should look into parallelism. If you're processing a dataset, like an array or a file line-by-line you could implement a recursive function to replace a loop and when you recurse instead of calling your function directly you can delay it with `setTimeout` so that you can resume your eventloop to avoid halting it for too long(to where timeout occur).

I cannot give you an exact time to which a synchronous task would be considered "too long". It really depends. There are far too many factors. How often this task occurs really makes a difference.

There are multiple approaches to handling these kinds of tasks:

1. Breaking up a serial task. Setting a timeout to break up portions of the task in your event loop like I mentioned before. Though if you have enough of these tasks it can still cause a problem.
2. Consider parallelism. Parallelism isn't a bad concept for removing a serial task from your event loop, but only if that event doesn't happen often. Parallelism has a lot of overhead.
3. Off loading to a worker. Push these event off to a worker or group of workers. This is very common and the only drawback is a slight increase in operation cost(possibly), and if you're not careful you can create something that is difficult to maintain(many small systems with no central convention).
4. Queuing and limiting concurrency. If the task is short, yet frequent you can simply queue them up and ensure that only a few of them get processed at a time so that your eventloop isn't blocked for too long.

If you're process is taking 2ms, it's likely that you'll be fine just letting the event loop handle it. Blocking the event loop for 2ms isn't a big deal. If these types of tasks are frequent(multiple times a second), then you may want to consider offloading to a worker or possibly creating some kind of queue or some method to limit how many are getting processed at a time. Otherwise you could stumble upon issues with slow responses. For now I think you'll be fine unless this is a very common task.

If your task is IO bound, the work of changing this to an asynchronous should be trivial, as nodejs is built from the ground up with this paradigm. It is bad practice if you do not use asynchronous methods when possible. Though this is only related to IO. If you're task is not reading/writing data to/from some source then asynchronous methods will do absolutely nothing for you.